# Is there a way to delay a program more precisely than with SDL_Delay?

Tags: c, sdl, delay

I found out that `SDL_Delay` isn't perfectly precise. The time waited by the program can be 1 or 2 more ms than the value passed as argument to the function. I read that this can happen depending on the OS used. Maybe for other people the gap is smaller or larger.

To make a program that displays ~60 frames per second, one needs to call `SDL_Delay` between each frame, in order for the program to wait for 17 ms (1000 / 60 = 16.6666...), or less depending on the time spent by other operations since the last call of `SDL_Delay`. However, by using this function, the time between each frame will be slightly different, sometimes 17ms, sometimes 18ms, sometimes 19ms... I would like know if there is any way to reproduce the behavior of `SDL_Delay`, but in a more precise way, without having the inconvenience of that gap.

Comment: What about the POSIX [`nanosleep()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html#) function?

Comment: @DavidBowling it works, ty

Comment: That looks like an XY problem. Why not wait for page-flip? Aour approach wasts time and cannot be reliable.

Comment: @Olaf I'm not sure what page-flip is. From what I just read on the internet, it looks like the double buff technique. Is there a difference? What do you mean by "waiting" for page-flip? And about the rest of your comment I would like you to add some explanations. I don't see how my approach wastes time and cannot be reliable

Comment: @nounoursnoir: Sure this is about multi-buffering. When the flip occurse depends on whether you use vsanc or not. It should be obvious why waiting for a time is waste: vsync is not exactly and you always have some margin. It also will becode asynchronous eventually without additional measures (resulting in bascially the same as I wrote, but more complicated).

Comment: Switch to C++ & use [`std::this_thread::sleep_for()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)?

Comment: It "should" not, for someone who doesn't know these things.

Comment: @genpfault I don't intend to switch from C to C++. I've never used C++, but from what I know, it's just a (really) little bit higher level than C. I read that C++ is an amelioration of C that provides an easier way to write object oriented code. I love hardcoding and even though some people say C++ is better to write games, I prefer to keep using C until a find a strong reason to switch to C++.

Comment: The main reason to switch to C++ for game programming that I have come across would be for objects with inheritance.  I certainly wouldn't be the one to try to convince you to switch, however, as I myself have in the past spent my free time designing a game engine in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is some way but it becomes **operating system specific**.

On ***Linux***, read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html), [nanosleep(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html), [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (or perhaps the old [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)), [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html), [timer_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) (or perhaps [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html))

Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (but some recent Linux features are not mentioned there, so see also [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) and [syscalls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)(2)).

Maybe you could be also interested by [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) (notably with `SIGALRM` and [setitimer(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html)), but then be sure to read [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)

On other operating systems it is different, and you need to find out.

Of course details are also hardware related (read about [HPET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer), [APIC timer](http://wiki.osdev.org/APIC_timer), [PIT](http://wiki.osdev.org/PIT))

SDL is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) and has (like all graphics toolkits) some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (see [SDL_WaitEventTimeout](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WaitEventTimeout)) probably around  [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) on Linux, so you could dive into the implementation.